# How to use single save and delete button for multiple page in asp .net or mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

In my last interview, the interviewer asked me this question. Question is:-
There are four pages having a different form, how to use common save, delete or update button for all the pages and also methods for all are common like save button will have a common function for all four pages. I have tried to answer as per my knowledge, but he is not satisfied with my answer. He said that, can we implement an interface for this purpose. But I am not able to answer him.
If you have any solution please suggest, thanks in advance.

My suggestion was based on MVC. I have told him that i have a common model for all four page with all required properties and a property have page name. In post method based on that property i use if else condition for different pages functionality.

Comment: What was your suggestion `as per your knowledge` to this question?

Comment: @Seany84 i have edited my question please check.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to have a master page which has Save, Update and Delete buttons.  Then these buttons along with all of their events are shared between all Forms which are having that master page.

Comment: @S Nash i know master page concept but the problem is that how can implement different functionality for the different pages, because all four pages have different form.

Comment: Let's say on Click event of Save button,  you can check the current page name and apply different actions.